# unable to list Evernote tags in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, evernote

I am unable to list the tags associated to a evernote note in vb.net

The note correctly displays its title, but the tagnames are [nothing]...

What am I doing wrong? Here's the code I used:

```
Imports System
Imports EvernoteSDK
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports EvernoteSDK.Advanced

Public class main
dim myResultsList As List(Of ENSessionFindNotesResult)
    ENSession.SetSharedSessionConsumerKey("KEY", "SECRET")

        If ENSession.SharedSession.IsAuthenticated = False Then
            ENSession.SharedSession.AuthenticateToEvernote()




myResultsList = ENSession.SharedSession.FindNotes(ENNoteSearch.NoteSearch("text to find"), Nothing, ENSession.SearchScope.All, ENSession.SortOrder.RecentlyUpdated, 500)

                  ' Given a NoteRef instance, download that note.
            Dim myDownloadedNote As ENNote = ENSession.SharedSession.DownloadNote(myResultsList(0).NoteRef)

            For i As Integer = 0 To myDownloadedNote.TagNames.Count - 1
                Note_tags_txt.Text = Note_tags_txt.Text + " " + myDownloadedNote.TagNames.Item(i)
            Next
end class
```

Comment: Evernote customer support just wrote me they do not have the tools to help with the API and to keep writing here.   
   

  The "GetNoteTagNames" does not seem to be recognized in vb.net, see below for the error message in Visual Studio.   
    
    
Could I have an example in VB.NET on how to get the tag names of a given note given the note guid?

Answer (score 0):

You won't get the note tag names back with the note - you'll get the tag guids. You can either
1. use [listTags](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_listTags) to cross-reference the tag guids to names, or
2. use [getNoteTagNames](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getNoteTagNames) to get the note tag names directly.

Comment: looks like it's `GetNoteTagNames` - see https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-windows/blob/master/src/EvernoteSDK/Advanced/ENNoteStoreClient.cs#L466.

Answer (score 0):

Well... I eventually figured it out myself... I have to remark that the vb.net SDK for Evernote is poorly documented.

First than all I had to have the following Imports

```
    Imports System
    Imports EvernoteSDK
    Imports System.IO
    Imports System.Collections.Generic
    Imports EvernoteSDK.Advanced
    Imports EvernoteSDK.Advanced.ENNoteStoreClient
    Imports Evernote.EDAM.NoteStore
    Imports Evernote.EDAM.Type
    Imports Evernote.EDAM.UserStore
```

Then I have to Authorize the application in two steps:

```
    ENSession.SetSharedSessionConsumerKey("KEY", "SECRET")
    ENSessionAdvanced.SetSharedSessionConsumerKey("KEY", "SECRET")

    If ENSession.SharedSession.IsAuthenticated = False Then
        ENSession.SharedSession.AuthenticateToEvernote()
    End If
```

Where "KEY" and "SECRET" is the API Token assigned by Evernote.

Since I did use the wrong code, I had to clear all files in **c:\users\%username%\appdata\local\evernote**, if I do not do so I get an EDAM error.

Saying that the notes I am interested in getting the tag names comes from a result of a search for the string "textToFind", I can get all the matching notes with:

```
     Dim myResultsList As List(Of ENSessionFindNotesResult) = _
ENSession.SharedSession.FindNotes(ENNoteSearch.NoteSearch(textToFind), Nothing, _
ENSession.SearchScope.All, ENSession.SortOrder.RecentlyUpdated, 500)
```

The above search can be restricted to a specific notebook by replacing "nothing" with the corresponding notebook.

Say I am interested in the tags of the first note of my zero-based list of results, then:

```
     Dim note_ref As ENNoteRef = myResultsList(0).NoteRef

     ' Given a NoteRef instance, download that note.
     Dim myDownloadedNote As ENNote = ENSession.SharedSession.DownloadNote(note_ref)
     Dim s = ENSessionAdvanced.SharedSession.NoteStoreForNoteRef(note_ref)
     Dim Tags_List As List(Of String) = s.GetNoteTagNames(note_ref.Guid)
```

In this way Tags_List will contain a list of tag names as strings. Then the rest of my code:

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To Tags_List.Count - 1
            If i = 0 Then
                Note_tags_txt.Text = Tags_List.Item(0)
            Else
                Note_tags_txt.Text = Note_tags_txt.Text + " - " + Tags_List.Item(i)
            End If
    Next i
```

Where Note_Tags_Txt is a label I created on my form.

I hope this helps someone.